# Strange behaviour of app when running as windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services, console

I'v created `C#` project with processing core ported from `C++` - core simply does the job - gets simple data, processes it and returns some result as again simple data.

This projects works OK when running as console app:

```
MainProcess main = new MainProcess();
main.Run(); //starts thread with main
main.Join(); //prevent main thread from terminating
```

When I change this to run as simplest windows process, with `MainProcess main = new MainProcess();` on initializing, `main.Run()` on start and `main.Abort() \\ aborts thread with main` on stop the core stops working correctly.

The core is some deterministic heurestic, which doesn't know anything but itself. It gets same data, but returns worse result, when whole app runs as service.

I checked, it is not some permission issue.

Do you have any idea what could possibly go wrong? It is exactly same code with this one small change. It returns always same result for same data (same for all console execution and same for all windows service execution).

So my question is: what different does it make when program is running as console app or as windows service?

Comment: What does "the core stops working correctly" mean? You've provided no information that can identify the problem, because you didn't tell us what the problem is in the first place. "stops working" is not helpful unless you explain what that means. "returns worse result" also tells us nothing, because "worse result" again has no meaning to anyone except you. We can't read your mind or see your code from here. :-) You need to explain the problem if you want us to help you solve it.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't think there is a problem with core itself. It was working before porting, it was working after porting as console app. Code is quite long and very complicated.

The question is what difference does it make when program is running as console app or windows service app, so I and people in similar situation could know, from which side they should debug it.

Comment: As I said, you've told us nothing about the problem. SO is for specific questions, not "Can you speculate what might be the cause of a problem I won't tell you about?" discussions. If you won't tell us in what way it's broken, we can't tell you what's wrong or how you can fix it. Your question needs to be clear and describe the actual problem, or it will most likely be closed as either "too localized" or "not a real question".

Comment: For what it's worth, a service should not make windows or write to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in some relative paths.

For example:

```
...
OpenFile("file.ext");
..
```

And `file.ext` exists in bin dir with `Program.exe`.

It works when you run this as console app, but when you try to run this as windows service then root directory would be different and program won't find `file.ext`.